# Many apps using one store in iOs

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios

How to make that, many applications from the same developer will use same store. 
It would be very usefull in case of synchronization procedures with use same data from same database.
Is it even possible to do this?

I guess I have to do something with boundle identyfier. Maybe something with * mark.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, the furthest you can go is sharing keychain items among your applications:

> It is now possible for you to share
>   Keychain items among multiple
>   applications you create. Sharing items
>   makes it easier for applications in
>   the same suite to interoperate more
>   smoothly. For example, you could use
>   this feature to share user passwords
>   or other elements that might otherwise
>   require you to prompt the user from
>   each application separately.
>
> Sharing Keychain items involves
>   setting up the proper entitlements in
>   your application binaries. Using
>   Xcode, you must create an Entitlements
>   property list file that includes the
>   supported entitlements for your
>   application. The process for creating
>   this file is described in iOS
>   Development Guide. For information
>   about the entitlements you can
>   configure, see the description for the
>   SecItemAdd function in Keychain
>   Services Reference.
>
> Accessing shared items at runtime
>   involves using the Keychain Services
>   programming interface with the access
>   groups you set up during development.
>   For information about how to access
>   the Keychain, see Keychain Services
>   Programming Guide.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOSv3.html

Answer (score -1):

Impossible. All apps are sandboxed.

Comment: @DBD So what's your answer to this question? Bear in mind I posted this almost 2 years ago.

Comment: I found this question/answer on current shared keychain search. As for sharing data across apps, `<Application_Home>/Documents/Inbox`. Apps can drop files off in the Inbox of other apps and those apps can read them. It's hardly tight data coupling, but it is used by many applications to share data. Mostly it's used to share documents, but you can use it to share .plist files. Not remotely ideal, but communication between apps does exist without an external server in the middle. I also removed my comment, it wasn't supposed to be a negative reflection on you, just stating inaccurate information

Comment: I believe I interpreted the question as asking whether you can share a Core Data store between apps (because of the tag).

Comment: I would agree with your interpretation, but it's not to difficult to export out and import in core data files.